# How to read parquet file from synapse dedicated SQL pool

Tags: azure-synapse, dedicated

I m trying to load parquet file into dedicated SQL pool table using copy command....same operation I'm able to do for gzip files CSV files etc ...for parquet seems some other settings required...

Please note I'm not using spark cluster in synapse and not serverless SQL pool as they both have ready to use facilities for parquet...I'm explicitly looking for dedicated SQL pool

Comment: `COPY INTO` supports parquet in dedicated SQL pools with the `FILE_TYPE = 'parquet' option.  See the main docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/copy-into-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) and show any code you have tried and specific error messages.

Comment: Copy into xyz from '.parquet' with (file_type='parquet'). This is my simple code n error is external file access failed due to internal error : parameters provided to connect to the azure storage account are not valid'. I also passed credentials as managed identity still same error ...I'm missing any parameters here